# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/qpid/proton/engine/Extendable

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-eventhub

I've created an EventHub to receive some random messages.

I was just trying to see if i can send messages from a java application.

Below is the code

```
package com.hasher.connectedcars.sender;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.*;

public class Sender {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceBusException,
        ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        final String namespaceName = "******************";
        final String eventHubName = "**************************";
        final String sasKeyName = "*******************";
        final String sasKey = "*******************";
        ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder(
                namespaceName, eventHubName, sasKeyName, sasKey);
        byte[] payloadBytes = "TEST MESSAGES"
                .getBytes("UTF-8");
        EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
        EventHubClient ehClient = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connStr.toString());
        ehClient.sendSync(sendEvent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the below compilation error from eclipse at

```
EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
```

> The type org.apache.qpid.proton.message.Message cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> ========================================================================= Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>
> ## org/apache/qpid/proton/engine/Extendable

Can someone point if I am missing some imports.

Thanks,

SriHarsha

Comment: You are missing the dependency class in the class path:  You must add the following four JAR files from the Apache Qpid JMS AMQP 1.0 distribution archive to the Java CLASSPATH when building and running JMS applications with Service Bus:

geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
qpid-amqp-1-0-client-[version].jar
qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-[version].jar
qpid-amqp-1-0-common-[version].jar

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it seems to be from the offical tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted/#send-messages-to-event-hubs.

I tried to reproduce your issue in my maven project, but failed. I added the maven dependency of [Azure EventHub SDK for Java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs/0.8.2) in the `pom.xml` file, then it works fine without `NoClassDefFoundError` exception. So I guess you might not use maven to build your project, then you need to manually add the dependency libraries into the classpath of your eclipse project.

Please try to use maven to build your project in Eclipse, or add these  dependencies ([proton-j](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/qpid/proton-j/0.14.0/proton-j-0.14.0.jar) & [bcpkix-jdk15on](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.49/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar)) into project classpath.
Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What is interesting is that you get this error with the latest version of the SDK ([0.9.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs/0.9.0)) even when using Maven. Going back to version [0.8.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventhubs/0.8.2) seems to be a workaround or, you can simply add the following to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>proton-j</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
```